# Any good tool(s) for Automating remote logging

Tags: automation

I need to write a script, that can automate few things:

a) telnet to a router

b) issue configuration commands.

c) check for status(success/error)

What language/framework should I use?

I only know about "expect".

What are other better alternatives?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you don't prefer expect? For tasks such as these, expect is *the* tool.

Comment: No specific reason, just want to know is there anything even better.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use expect, you're probably going to end up using some more standard scripting language which is less specifically well-suited to the task. If you get into that realm, the proper answer is "anything you feel comfortable with", be that bash, python, or whatever else.

It's a pretty general problem, so use whatever produces an easy-to-maintain system.

Comment: I came here expecting to post about expect.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of Jcraft an open source tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Ganymed SSH2 a Java Open Source API to connect to Remote Machines. I used it for secured remote login. You may even check my blog for referene
http://allianceglobalservices.com/blog/terminal-window-automation-using-ganymedssh-2-api